# How to add an IPv6 routing rule with systemd-networkd?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I'm running on systemd 242 (Ubuntu Eoan) and am trying to do something equivalent to the following `iproute2` command with systemd-networkd:

```bsh
ip -6 rule add from all table 1 pref 1000
```

This is what I have in `/etc/systemd/network/10-eno1.network` but it's not working:

```
[RoutingPolicyRule]
Table=1
Priority=1000
Family=ipv6
```

I also tried `Family=both`, but only the v4 rule was generated.

I've read the whole of https://systemd.network/systemd.network.html#%5BRoutingPolicyRule%5D%20Section%20Options but still don't know what's wrong.

I want to do this with `systemd-networkd` and I'm not interested in a solution writing a service with `ExecStart=/sbin/ip blah blah` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My actual config file was missing the line `From=::/0` and was relying on `Family=ipv6` (or `both`). As suggested by [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13233), `Family=` is not a key in systemd 242 (new in 243), so `From=::/0` is still necessary.